# Drawing arrow continuum with layered mark-ups

Tags: arrows, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, labels

I am trying to draw a simple continuum, which looks like below. Can somebody help me achieve this in the most economical way please? I'm very new to LaTeX and have been learning codes using examples, but I haven't been able to locate one that looks exactly like what I want here. Any help would be extremely appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most difficult part of answering such questions is to punch in texts from a screen shot (and trying to decipher them).

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every pin/.append style={text width=8em},
    every pin edge/.style={draw},node distance=5em]
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=bb]
\setlist{topsep=0em,itemsep=0.2ex}
 \node[pin=below:{\begin{itemize}
  \item[~] Syntax
 \end{itemize}}](COP){COP};
 \node[right=of COP,pin=below:{\begin{itemize}
  \item[~] Syntax
  \item[+] Normal
 \end{itemize}}](PAR){PAR};
 \node[right=of PAR,pin=below:{\begin{itemize}
  \item[~] Syntax
  \item[+] Normal
  \item[+] obc
 \end{itemize}}](LOT){LOT};
\end{scope}
\draw[thick,-stealth] 
 ([yshift=1em]bb.north west) node[above right]{$-$}
 -- ([yshift=1em]bb.north east) node[above left,align=center]{Change\\ $+$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll try to write more legibly next time :)